# add buffer to vim from the shell command line

Tags: command-line, buffers

I am currently trying to externally add a new buffer to a vim instance from the command line.

That means I have already opened vim and I modify the files of interest to me.
Then I want to go back to my bash line, so I do `Ctrl + z`, which makes my vim task go to the "Stopped" state.
Later I find myself to a completely irrelevant directory, wanting to edit a file. Because I don't want to open a lot of vim instances, I would like to have this added in my previous vim task (short of like most of the non-cli text editors work out there)

I am lazy. I don't want to go back to my vim instance with `fg` and do `:edit /a/very/long/path/file`

I want to do a magic `add_buffer_to_vim ./file` and immediately open my previous vim instance with the new buffer loaded and ready to edit.

Also I am running vim in a machine without admin rights, so installing/compiling new vi flavors is not a possibility.

I hope I am not asking for much. Thanks!

Comment: I use neovim in tui to avoid nonsenses like this.

Comment: have a look at `:h client-server`

Comment: You may want to read [How to open new files in a same Vim instance from my file manager or from command-line?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/588202).

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose Vim is running, you can use Vim remote to send commands. I suggest  to keep it running (i.e. `bg` after `ctrl z`) and then use `vim --remote` to send an edit command to it.

If you don't want to do this, a possible solution is to use a file that will contain a file list. Vim will check it when running and load buffers from this file.

Use `au GuiEnter` maybe.

Comment: Cool. I found the first approach the one more appropriate for me. Although I cannot understand why do you suggest `bg` after `ctrl z` ? To me it works the same anyway.

Comment: I wasn't sure about the exact state of the job. It is supposedly stopped.